# Change image src back and forth after first click

Tags: javascript, html

What I want to happen is... when the image 'x' is clicked i want it to change image then when it is clicked again i want it to change back so on and so fourth, however I only want this to happen on the second click.

So X is clicked & nothing happens,
Then when it is clicked again it changes images,
and then back after another click, and then it alternates back and forth after that,
until the page resets, then i want it to reset as well.

this is my code so far:

```
document.getElementById('x').onclick = function() {
    var ClickedOnce = 0;
    if (this.src == 'Media/Images/Other/SwitchUP.jpg') {
    ClickedOnce + 1
}
if (this.src == 'Media/Images/Other/SwitchUP.jpg' && ClickedOnce > 1) {
    this.src = 'Media/Images/Other/SwitchDOWN.jpg';
} else if ('Media/Images/Other/SwitchDOWN.jpg') {
    this.src = 'Media/Images/Other/SwitchUP.jpg';
}
}
```

Comment: You can always use something like jsfiddle which has a built-in javascript lint that you can use to check the validity of your code.

Comment: Well... You could do it another way.

    `<img src='Media/Images/Other/SwitchUP.jpg' onclick="MyFunction(this);" />`

and then in javascript

    `function MyFunction(o) {
        if (o.src == 'Media/Images/Other/SwitchUP.jpg') {
            o.src = 'Media/Images/Other/SwitchDOWN.jpg';
        } else {
            o.src = 'Media/Images/Other/SwitchUP.jpg';
        }
    }`

Comment: use `getAttribute` to retrieve the `src`-attribute, the `src`-property will return the complete path and the comparisions will not work as expected. Furthermore: the `else if`-condition at the end always returns true.

Comment: This questions seems to make sense to me..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the reason this isn't working is because you are declaring the var ClickedOnce inside of a function. This means that it is a local variable inside that function that will be set to 0 every time that function is called. Therefore, the same thing will happen every time it is clicked.

Try declaring some variable outside of the function.

You can try something like this:

```
var wasClicked = false;

document.getElementById('x').onclick = function() {
    if (!wasClicked) {
        wasClicked = true;
        return;
    }
    if (this.getAttribute("src") == 'Media/Images/Other/SwitchUP.jpg') {
        this.setAttribute("src", 'Media/Images/Other/SwitchDOWN.jpg');
    } else {
        this.setAttribute("src", 'Media/Images/Other/SwitchUP.jpg');
    }
}
```

Additionally, since you tagged this question with jQuery, here is a jQuery approach to it:

```
var wasClicked = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#x").click(function() {
        if (!wasClicked) {
            wasClicked = true;
            return;
        }
        if ($(this).attr("src") == "path/to/some/image") {
            $(this).attr("src", "path/to/other/image");
        } else {
            $(this).attr("src", "path/to/some/image");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: take out the `return;` else it will never reach the if statement or change the logic there. This whole function/statement doesn't make sense.

Comment: The `return;` is necessary. The asker wants to do nothing the first time the image is clicked. That is why I check inside the if statement to see if it had been clicked yet. If it has not, then it returns (doing nothing). Every time after that, wasClicked will be true, and it will evaluate the rest of the function.

Comment: An alternative I couldn't post because this was closed while I was typing it up, was for the first click setup the onclick to = a toggle function, then from there on out, toggle: Could try something like this:

    // first click - set the click event to the toggle
    document.getElementById('x').onclick = function() {
        this.onclick = toggleImages();
    }

    // toggle
    function toggleImages() {
        var up = 'Media/Images/Other/SwitchUP.jpg';
        var down = 'Media/Images/Other/SwitchDOWN.jpg';
    
        this.src = (this.src == up) ? down : up;
    }

Comment: @Steven It seems to make sense to me but it's not working and i can't find a single reason why :(

Comment: @KyeGregory, it may be as Dr. Molle pointed out in the comment that src will return the full path. Try using the `getAttribute` function instead. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Furthermore, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is a great tool to test out some javascript. [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/) is a great source to look at some references.